# Handling ItemUpdating event receiver firing more than once

Tags: event-receivers, item-updating

The reason why item-updating event receiver fires twice in case of document libraries is because of check-in/checkout.

Also it can fire twice in case of doc library/list if we are updating the current item values with in this item updating event.

How can we handle both these cases via code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the scenario when you are the one triggering the second `ItemUpdating` by changing item values you can use the `EventFiringEnabled` parameter (you should use a `try - catch -finally` around it):

```
this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
// Do the changes
item.Update();
this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
```

The other scenario is tougher, and the reason behind why I use `ItemUpdated` instead when ever possible!

You could check  the `BeforeProperties`, `ListItem` and `AfterProperties`in your `ItemUpdating` event receiver to check if there is updates being made that you have to take action on. If not, then just `return`.

[Here is a guide](http://howididit-sharepoint.blogspot.se/2012/09/dismistifying-afterproperties.html) for when you can use `.BeforeProperties`and when you should go in the `.ListItem` instead

Comment: Is this also applicable to item-updated events?

Comment: You really should not add more questions to a question after receiver answers (it could mean the existing answers looks strange if oyu know what I mean). But yes, you can use the `EventFiringEnabled` in `ItemUpdated` to, but you can not use `AfterProperties` (since the item is already updated when this event i triggered)

Comment: Robert, what did you mean in your answer by "The other scenario is tougher", which scenario?

Comment: The one you talk about first (check-in / check-out), it's quite clear in my post I think

Answer (score 5):

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
  try
  {
    //is the item checked out?
    if (isCheckin(properties) == false)
    {
         this.EventFiringEnabled = false;

         //do your stuff

    }
  }
  catch(Exception a)
  {
    //catch any errors
  }
  finally
  {
    this.EventFiringEnabled = true; 
  }
} 

private bool isCheckin(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    if (properties.AfterProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"] == null 
         && properties.BeforeProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"] != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/managing-itemupdating-and-itemupdated-events-firing-twice-in-a-sharepoint-item-event-receiver/

@Robert about the before properties, yes your right they would be the same regardless.... only possible solution that i can think of would be using this instead

```
private bool isCheckin(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    string BeforeVal = properties.ListItem["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"];

    if (properties.AfterProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"] == null 
         && BeforeVal != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The `isCheckin` method is pretty sweet! Never seen that one before

Comment: yup encountered it a few years back when i had similar issue!, the key is checking both properties of the checked state field and from that we know if its checked in or out

Comment: The only problem I can see with it is for Lists (not libraries) where `BeforeProperties` is always empty

Comment: Clever, but shouldn't EventFiringEnabled be scoped in using or try catch finally, to make sure its turned back to its original state if an error occurs

Comment: Here is some cool examples for how to create a scope of it @AndersAune http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/disable-item-events-firing-during-item-update/